# Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Installed, now get error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, visual-studio, iis-7

"The web application project is configured to use IIS.  Unable to access the IIS Meta Base.  You do not have sufficient privilege to access the IIS web sites on your machine"

Just installed Service Pack 1 yesterday.  This error was not present before SP1, so I'm pretty sure it is SP1 that caused it.  However, I need SP1 for future projects/work that requires it.  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this from the command line:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Check your version "v2.0.50727"